# VBA Loop Function based on value from a list

Tags: excel, vba

Ok So i have been trying to come up with something to run this.

basically I need to Loop through a value on column A in Sheet 2, for each value it needs to find it in sheet 1, then based on an identifer (4 variables) in column H add a count to a cell, if it meets one criteria then it may need to check column K to know which value.

For example:

Start in Sheet 2 row 2 which has number "123456789", in sheet 1 find row which has number "123456789" in Column B. (therefore found in B*) 
If H* has one value then it needs to add a value to a the logger in the correct column in sheet 2 for that number. If H* = a certain criteria then it needs to check a criteria in column K and then add the value to the correct column.
I am just completely lost with how to set this up.
Any help would be amazing, many thanks

Jon

Code is now as follows:
    Sub Status_Track()

```
Dim a As Long 'topic number
Dim Z As Integer
Dim R As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim S As Integer
Dim D As Integer

Worksheets("RAW").Activate
R = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
C = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Z = 0
i = 2
Do Until i > R

'ident
If Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2) And (Cells(i, 13) = "ERKA")Then
Z = Cells(i, 6) + 1
Worksheets("RAW").Cells(i, 6).Value = Z
 Else
 If Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2) And (Cells(i, 13) = "INBA") Then
 'Inba
 Z = Cells(i, 7) + 1
 Worksheets("RAW").Cells(i, 7).Value = Z
  Else
  If Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2) And (Cells(i, 13) = "ABGE") Then
  'Abge
  Z = Cells(i, 8) + 1
  Worksheets("RAW").Cells(i, 8).Value = Z
   Else
   If Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2) And (Cells(i, 13) = "GELO") Then
   'Gelo
   Z = Cells(i, 5) + 1
   Worksheets("RAW").Cells(i, 5).Value = Z
    Else
    If Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2) And (Cells(i, 13) = "UEBE") And (Cells(i, 11) = 0) Then
    'UEBE
    Z = Cells(i, 10) + 1
    Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 9).Value = Z
     Else
     If Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "<1") Then
    '1
     Z = Cells(i, 10) + 1
     Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 10).Value = Z
     Else
     If Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "6") Then
      '6
      Z = Cells(i, 10) + 1
      Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 11).Value = Z
       Else
       If Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "9") Then
       '9
       Z = Cells(i, 10) + 1
       Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 12).Value = Z
        Else
        If Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "10") Then
        '10
        Z = Cells(i, 10) + 1
        Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 13).Value = Z
        Else
        If Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "15") Then
         '15
         Z = Cells(i, 10) + 1
         Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 14).Value = Z
          Else
          If Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "30") Then
          '30
          Z = Cells(i, 10) + 1
          Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 15).Value = Z
           Else
           If Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "50") Then
           '50
           Z = Cells(i, 10) + 1
           Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 16).Value = Z
            Else
            If Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "60") Then
            '60
            Z = Cells(i, 10) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 17).Value = Z
             Else
             If Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "70") Then
             '70
             Z = Cells(i, 10) + 1
             Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 18).Value = Z
              Else
              If Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "80") Then
              '80
              Z = Cells(i, 10) + 1
              Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 19).Value = Z
               Else
               If Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "90") Then
               '90
               Z = Cells(i, 10) + 1
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 20).Value = Z
                Else
                If Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "97") Then
                '97
                 Z = Cells(i, 10) + 1
                 Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 21).Value = Z
                 Else
                 If Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "100") Then
                 '100
                 Z = Cells(i, 10) + 1
                 Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 22).Value = Z
                End If
               End If
              End If
             End If
            End If
           End If
          End If
         End If
        End If
       End If
      End If
     End If
    End If
   End If
  End If
 End If
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have example of iterating over Excell Sheet cells:

```
Sub test()
    Dim range1 As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set range1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Your sheet name").Range("A1:A5")

    For Each cell In range1
        Debug.Print cell.Value
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Instead of `Debug.Print` you can add another loop to check for values in different worksheet.

Comment: Thanks,

I seem to have written out a code, but I keep getting error maeesages.
I also Can't upload it here as it is too long

Comment: Error overflow. 
The code above is as far As i've got but it doesn't seem to work.